# Problems to authenticate correctly with pysimplesoap

Tags: python, soap, pysimplesoap

I'm trying to use pysimplesoap to communicate with the Websitepanel SOAP-API. 
The WebsitePanel API Introduction says:

> For interacting with WebsitePanel API you should use Basic Authentication. WebsitePanel recognizes “Authorization” header with the user credentials provided in the following format: username:password

My first try was the following:

```
client = SoapClient(wsdl=endpoint_url, trace=True)
client['Authorization'] = "%s:%s" % (username, password)
```

which returns a 401 "Unauthorized".
Second try was:

```
client = SoapClient(wsdl=endpoint_url, trace=True)          
client['wsse:Security'] = {
    'wsse:UsernameToken': {
        'wsse:Username': username,
        'wsse:Password': password,
    }
}
```

which works as expected but returns the following:

```
status: 500
content-length: 924
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
cache-control: private
date: Tue, 12 Feb 2013 14:23:56 GMT
content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

And

```
pysimplesoap.client.SoapFault: q0:Security: SOAP response should be signed.
```

Why does `client['Authorization']` not work and what is meant by the `Response should be signed` error message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: To authenticate correctly with pysimplesoap you have to call

```
client = SoapClient(wsdl=u, trace=True, 
                    http_headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % encoded})
```

with `encoded`beeing the base64-encoded string `username:password`

Comment: I tried this, but SoapClient's initializer doesn't accept the keyword parameter `http_headers`.  Is this code sample correct?

Comment: I'm using version 1.07a - and it works fine. Actual signature of the SoapClient s initializer is:     `def __init__(self, location = None, action = None, namespace = None,
                 cert = None, trace = False, exceptions = True, proxy = None, ns=False,
                 soap_ns=None, wsdl = None, cache = False, cacert=None,
                 sessions=False, soap_server=None, timeout=_USE_GLOBAL_DEFAULT,
                 http_headers={}
                 )`